# When bone moves across the y-axis, move bone2 across the x-axis

Tags: armature, bones, constraints

I need to move the child across the x-axis when I move the parent across the y-axis. I think the Transformation Constraint is the one I need, and I couldn't figure out how to use it correctly. Here is my setup:

[image: Bone setup]

If possible, how do I get the side bones to move closer to the center bone when I move the center bone down the y-axis? And vise versa?

Answer (score -1):

You'd have to use constraints but i haven't actually used those yet. It gives the same effect as paint weights on a model but for bones.